# Can a transistor be constructed using diodes?

Tags: transistors, diodes

Can a transistor be constructed using diodes?

Can we use diodea as a transistor? I have gotten a assignment to give a presentation on this. I’m unable to understand the question and would like help from the people.

Comment: The question is not clear. If it is about a diode being a pn junction and a transistor being a npn or pnp transistor, or if it about using diodes might be used in circuited as transistors for example Google diode resistor logic.

Comment: The materials need to directly interact, therefore how the material and how it interfaces to the silicon matters. That means the metal wire and bond wires make a difference. For example, just connecting a chunk of P and N silicon together with a wire won't make a diode.  Even pressing them together isn't enough because the interface surfaces need to be very, very carefully prepared. Example: If a schottky diode is metal-silicon junction, then why don't the bond wires from every semiconductor make a diode? Because they are prepared differently. (metal-silicon vs PN vs ohmic junctions)

Answer (score 5):

Although a transistor contains two back to back diodes, one cannot construct a transistor from two discrete diodes.

In a transistor, the emitter-base diode and the base-collector diode *share* the base as one side of each diode. This is critical for transistor operation. The base-collector diode is (when the transistor is not saturated) *reverse* biased. A reverse biased diode generally has only a small leakage current flowing through it. That is the case in a discrete diode. However, in a transistor, the base is heavily populated by minority carriers that came into the base from the emitter. These minority carriers easily cross the reverse biased base-collector junction, and the "leakage" current of that junction can become almost that of the current from emitter to base.

Since a reverse biased discrete diode does not have (many) minority carriers, flowing from the metallic leads, the mechanism that leads to transistor action is missing in discrete diodes

Answer (score 0):

This is a good and a very common question amongst students from introductory courses on electronics and semiconductors.

The short answer is NO. The distance between P-N junctions plays a pivotal role in the design, fabrication and operation of transistors.

Let's consider a BJT NPN transistor.  Both P-N junctions form difussion regions that must be polarised accordingly to turn the transistor ON. The B-E area is typically larger than the B-C area while the region of the base in the epitaxial process is very thin. Each area will have a *limited* number of donors and acceptors that will diffuse through the N- and P-doped materials once the electric field is formed. If you put two diodes back-to-back you are effectively affecting the distance between junctions and thus the diffusion regions breaking the junctions apart by splitting the base which acts as an *intermediary* in triggering the Collector-Emitter current. More on this [here](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Base-region-of-a-bipolar-junction-transistor#:%7E:text=The%20base%20region%20of%20a,emitter%20and%20the%20collector%20regions.)

Pay close attention to the following circuit. Is there any current flowing through Collector-Emitter? Are you effectively controlling the load with an *electronic switch*?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnSOgD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>